# Different versions of MediaWiki on the same server

Tags: php, mediawiki

From what I can tell, people install multiple instances of MediaWiki on the same server all the time. However, I am not sure if you can install different versions of MediaWiki on the same server. Basically, I have a host running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with two wikis using MediaWiki (1.17.0) and PHP (5.3.6). I want to create a new wiki with the latest version of MediaWiki (1.25.2).  From reading the docs, I learned that MediaWiki 1.25.2 requires PHP 5.3.5+, so I do not need to install another version of PHP. Will the different versions of MediaWiki be able to coexist in harmony? Oddly enough, I have been prowling the internet and cannot seem to find a straight answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work fine.  Be sure to keep them in separate paths and use separate databases for them, but otherwise you should see no trouble.

Whether there is any reason to do this or why you might want to do it on Windows is another question entirely, but there is no reason it shouldn't work.